# Exporting Processing Modeler as Python script in QGIS 3?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-3

How do I export my model from Processing Modeler as `.py` so that I can edit its code?

This does not seem as intuitive as in previous QGIS versions.

Answer (score 9):

Early versions of QGIS 3 did not support exporting models to scripts (See: [Why "Export as Python script" button is unaccessible in QGIS 3.0/3.1 Modeler by default?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277884/why-export-as-python-script-button-is-unaccessible-in-qgis-3-0-3-1-modeler-by?noredirect=1&lq=1))

From QGIS 3.6, the export to script button is back and creates a proper QGIS3 Processing script:

[image]