# Why "Export as Python script" button is unaccessible in QGIS 3.0/3.1 Modeler by default?

Tags: qgis-processing, qgis-modeler, qgis-3

In QGIS 3.0, "Processing Modeler" window has no "Export as Python script" button unlike QGIS 2.x.

[image: QGIS 3.0 Processing Modeler Window]

If you look at the codes (in `DlgModeler.ui` and `ModelerDialog.py` files), you see the code lines related to that button.

in `ModelerDialog.py` (commented):

```
#self.mActionExportPython.triggered.connect(self.exportAsPython)
.
.
#self.mActionExportPython.setIcon(
#            QgsApplication.getThemeIcon('/mActionSaveAsPython.svg'))
```

in `DlgModeler.ui`:

```
<action name="mActionExportPython">
  <property name="text">
    <string>Export as Python script...</string>
  </property>
  <property name="toolTip">
   <string>Export as Python script</string>
  </property>
</action>
```

After some editings I explained [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277878/exporting-processing-modeler-as-python-script-in-qgis-3-0), "Export as Python script" button came into view.

[image]

Is there a specific reason or is it a mistake?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was intentionally disabled by commit [4f2a464](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/4f2a4644dbdde1a4fa72b876f80c82cb6320dbe5#diff-bc1a2e8ba90b985e0c9c4dc36e2fc4d7)

> [processing] remove obsolete code and disable exporting models as
>   script until we update it so support new scripts format
>
> @alexbruy alexbruy committed on 2 Feb

So re-enabling it yourself won't be of any use as the output code won't be usable in QGIS 3x.

Answer (score 7):

Check https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/313547/187 for updates post 3.1!

Spoiler: it's back!

[image]