# Merging two processes in QGIS3 to one?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-processing, saga, taudem

Is there any way to merge several processes in QGIS3 into one process?

Or is there a way to look at the source code of different processes under QGIS3 and combine them under one function?

I am trying to create one file (in Python) with all the processes under one single process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is processing modeler in QGIS which you can access in the "Processing" tab on the ribbon. It allows you to combine multiple steps in geoprocessing. I'm not sure if there is a way to export a model as a python script, you can definitely do that in ArcMap.

Here is a guide to use Processing Modeler: [Official QGIS guide](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing/modeler.html). Another one by Carleton University which I found more detailed/helpful: [Automating Vector and Raster Workflows using the Graphical Modeler in QGIS](http://gracilis.carleton.ca/CUOSGwiki/index.php/Automating_Vector_and_Raster_Workflows_using_the_Graphical_Modeler_in_QGIS).

Update: there is a way to export the QGIS 3 Model as a script, but it would only be usable in QGIS 2 environment: [source](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277878/exporting-processing-modeler-as-python-script-in-qgis-3-0)

Comment: Thank you! You mentioned this could be done in ArcMap as well, could you link me somewhere that will help me get started with the process! I appreciate it.

Comment: If there are no QGIS 3-specific functions that you need, you might as well just use QGIS 2 and export a script there, which would be usable within QGIS 2 environment (you can have an older version of QGIS installed that wouldn't impact your newer version). Here is a guide for Model Builder in ArcMap: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/what-is-modelbuilder.htm

Comment: Is there any way to run this exported script from QGIS through PyCharm or any other IDE?

Comment: I'm not sure about these, as I'm not that proficient in Python. You should be able to execute it as a tool or run it in QGIS console.