# Model in QGIS 3 (.model3) to Python 3?

Tags: export, qgis-3, qgis-modeler, python-3, pyqgis-3

I try to export a QGIS 3 model (.model3) to Python but the functionality that was available in QGIS 2 doesn't exist anymore. Is there a way to export it ?

Comment: Nobody has an answer to this problem ?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277878/exporting-processing-modeler-as-python-script-in-qgis-3-0